# jQuery UI Dialog Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I have my jQuery UI Dialog have links within the dialog open inside the dialog (without changing the parent page)?

Comment: Uhm... to navigate throw dialogs? I don't understand at all what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use one of 2 options  for this.

AJAX: If your dialog box is a `div`, You'll need to repopulate that div with the correct HTML fetched from the desired page.

(jQuery Ajax Example)

```
$('#modalDiv').load(url); //Where URL is the desired page
```

JS/Iframe: If you're pulling a full page into the modal div, you might want to try using an iframe

```
document.getElementById('modalDiv').innerHTML='<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
```